# Liferay: Form and ActionPhase

Tags: java, forms, liferay, action, liferay-aui

I have problems getting along with Liferay forms and action phase.
I always get this Errorcode:

New error:

> 00:01:21,547 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-153][PortletServlet:116] javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.consist.weiterbildung.WBM_Portlet.ePfadAnmelden(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)
>   javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.consist.weiterbildung.WBM_Portlet.ePfadAnmelden(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)

Old error:

> Jan 04, 2015 9:07:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /html/wbm/user/ePfadAnmelden.jsp (line: 58, column: 91) equal symbol expected

ePfadAnmelden.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL var="ePfadAnmelden" name="ePfadAnmelden">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/wbm/user/ePfad.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%=ePfadAnmelden%>" method="post">

    <aui:input type="radio" name="kernsek" value="kern" checked="true"/>
    <aui:input type="radio" name="kernsek" value="sek"/>

    <aui:button type="sumbit" value="Anmelden"/>
</aui:form>
```

WBM_Portlet.java

```
public void ePfadAnmelden(ActionRequest request,
    ActionResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException
    {
        PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();
        String kernsek = request.getParameter("kernsek");

        if(kernsek != null)
        {
            prefs.setValue("kernsek", kernsek);
            prefs.store();
        }

        String mvcPath = request.getParameter("mvcPath");

        response.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", mvcPath);
    }
```

I want to fill the form in `ePfadAnmelden`, do some stuff in the `ePfadAnmelden` method in `WMB_Portlet.java` and then show some values in `ePfad.jsp`.

And how can I get just a variable via the form?

Comment: aui elements add portlet namespace as prefix to any input parameter name. Use `ParamUtil.get(request,"kernsek");` to get parameter in portlet class.

Comment: That do not help me.

Comment: For the above error please check if you are missing any double quotes or single quotes in your JSP or if you are having an attribute value without escaping the inner string like `var="this is "in quotes" value"` (notice the "in quotes" string)

Comment: The double quotes and strings are all correct. (At least I cannot find any noncorrect)

Comment: You quote less than 58 rows of your jsp, but the problem points to line 58. What is the content in (and around) that line?

Comment: It was just inside of a string of one of the radiobuttons, but when I changed the file with just adding few empty lines the error was still on the same (empty) place. But now (I did not changed anything) I get a different error (see edited post).